# jquery dataTables - creating a column with static content

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following logic to create a jquery dataTable:

```
  var selected = [];
    $('#users').DataTable( {
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
         aLengthMenu: [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "-1"],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "ajax": "/cgi-bin/pid_list",
        "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
        "columns": 
        [    
                { "data": "id" ,"searchable":false},
                { "data": "name","searchable":true},    
                { "data": "pnumber", "searchable":true },    
                { "data": "destination", "searchable":true },
                { "defaultContent": "<button id=showgrp>Show</button>"},
                { "mRender": function ( data, type, row) {
                        var temp = formatnameURI(row.name);
                        if (row.destination=='Group') {
                                return '<a href=update.html?id=' + row.id + '&pid=' + row.pnumber + '&destination=' + row.destination + '&name=' + temp + '>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# onclick=delete(' + row.id + ',' + row.pnumber + ',true)>Delete</a>';

                        } else {
                                return '<a href=add.html?id='+ row.id +'&pid='+row.pnumber + '&destination='+row.destination+'&name='+temp+'>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp<a href=# onclick=delete('+row.id+','+row.pnumber+',0)>Delete</a>';
                        } 
                    }
                }
        ]
    } );
```

So far, so good.  Everything works.  But now I need to rig up my "Show" button so that when it's clicked, it triggers an ajax call to the database and displays a dialog box.

This is the line in question:

```
  { "defaultContent": "<button id=showgrp>Show</button>"},
```

In order to make the ajax call to the database, I need to know the value in the "id" column for that particular row.  In other words, I need the data from this column:

```
{ "data": "id" ,"searchable":false},
```

I was hoping to embed the "id" as a part of either the id tag on the button, something like

```
  <button id = showgrp_XX>Show</button>
```

where XX is the value of the id column.

I'm currently reading over the dataTables manual but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test it, I would say you should do

```
{ 
   mRender : function(data, type, row) {
       return '<button data-id="'+row.id+'">Show</button>'
   }
}
```

instead of

```
{ "defaultContent": "<button id=showgrp>Show</button>"},
```

When the button is clicked, you can retrieve the id

```
$("#users").on('click', 'button', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    ...
});
```

example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6nckztco/**

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0tux2m12/) is an editable demo that uses the Javascript sourced data example from [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: Why not `render` instead of `mRender`, it's clearly DataTables 1.10?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, or _why_ use `render` if OP prefers the `mRender` naming? `render` is just an alias of `mRender`, in fact dataTables will add a `mRender` method to the options literal if you are using `render`, like it will add an `aoColumns` if you are using `columns` and so on. See example ->  http://jsfiddle.net/3w54yhg5/ (look in the console, same as above changed a bit) but agree that `render` is more readable; people should consider using 1.10.x naming and at least get rid of the ¤%# quoting fashion around keys, like `"ordering" : false` etc It is really bad :)

Comment: @Zack, thank you - but I meant I am not able to reproduce OP's scenario in depth 1:1, i.e same data, by ajax and so on - but I am sure the above solution works.

Comment: `render` is preferred because according to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-naming): *Please note that the Hungarian notation option is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of the extensions*.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - as long as dataTables are using the hungarian notation internally, as it still does - and consistently translates the new camelCase notation to hungarian notation so dataTables internals can "understand" the camelCase notation, as I demonstrated above, and as long v2.0 not even is scheduled, there is no reason for not using hungarian notation other than consistency and readability. The 1.10.x camelCase notation is in fact by now just a mapping to the hungarian notation. But I prefer the 1.10.x camelCase too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Must avoid (,) spliter in like<name="" ,class=""> so resolve it

  {
  "data": null, "defaultContent":'<input type="checkbox" name="IndividualCheckboxes" class="SingleCheckboxes" style="cursor:pointer;" id="'+this.id +'"/>',


                },
```

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your approach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

You can register `onclick` event for each button and pass `'this'` reference.

```
<button onclick="showID(this);">Show</button>
```

---

```
function showID(currButton){
dTable = $('#users').DataTable();
rowIndex = dTable.$(currButton).parent().parent().index();  // This is jQuery, you may want to find more efficient traversing ways.
idVal = dTable.cell(rowIndex,0).data();
}
```